# Is there anything missing in my code while exporting to excel from php

Tags: php, phpexcel

My function

```
 function xlstest(){
            $headers='SN'."\t".'Reservation ID'."\t".'Hotel Name'."\t".'Customer Name';
            $data='1'."\t".'234'."\t".'My hotel name'."\t".'Jonny';
            $filename='testing';
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");
            echo "$headers\n$data";
        }
```

while calling this function in admin panel it will export to excel but file doesn't have above headers and data but it shows all the text that is present in admin panel
[image]

Do anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. Actually I have called this function just below the `<link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>`  and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".... .."></script>
```

once i moved above these css and scripts.. my problem is solved strange.......

Answer (score 0):

Your are not using [phpexcel](/questions/tagged/phpexcel) api at all. Please read the [documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) and try to use the api.

And about the codes you are using, separate the field using `\t`(with spaces back and front).
Also, instead of `octet-stream` use excels header file.

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
```

Usage:

```
function xlstest(){
    $headers='SN'." \t ".'Reservation ID'." \t ".'Hotel Name'." \t ".'Customer Name';
    $data='1'." \t ".'234'." \t ".'My hotel name'." \t ".'Jonny';
    $filename='testing';
    header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo "$headers\n$data";
}
```

**Update**:

To export a CSV file you can do do the following. Its almost same, but the delimiter is a comma instead and, the content-type is `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

```
function csvtest(){
    $headers='SN'.",".'Reservation ID'.",".'Hotel Name'.",".'Customer Name';
    $data='1'.",".'234'.",".'My hotel name'.",".'Jonny';
    $filename='testing';
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo "$headers\n$data";
}
```

Comment: I used to export just by using these headers.. this time i dont know what is the probelm.. let me check the space issue...

Comment: @sujal, Also, it would be easy to export the data as `.csv` file and later access it through, excel, it is basically the same thing.

Comment: what should i do to change in .csv? just changing the header will work?>

Comment: @sujal, No I haven't tried your code, and see the code for CSV example.